# How to launch an external Python program from Meson?

Tags: python, build, meson-build

Before building my project, I have to generate a C++ source file through a Python script, using the Meson build system.

Is this the correct way, i.e. consider Python as a generic external command?

```
# meson.build
r = run_command('python', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
if r.returncode() != 0
  error('Error message')
endif
```

Or, being Meson itself a Python program, is it possible to do the same thing in a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your build definition more robust, you can try to find python executable at first with [*find_program()*](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#find_program). This will stop build with verbose reason if python can't be found (You may alter this behavior by passing `required: false` as an argument).

Then, to ensure that there are no path issues if your arguments are files or directories, make sure to wrap those with [*files()*](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#files).

All in all:

```
python_exe = find_program('python3', 'python')
params = files('file1', 'dir/file2')

r = run_command(python_exe, params, 'arg1', 'arg2')
if r.returncode() != 0
    error('Error message')
endif
```

---

You may also consider defining your code-generation via python with actual building targets, e.g. [*generator()*](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#generator) or [*custom_target()*](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#custom_target). This way, you can use the code-generation target as a dependency for actual c++ compiling target, therefore, it is guaranteed that code will be generated first and only then compiled.

Comment: This is a more portable method: https://mesonbuild.com/Python-3-module.html#find_python

Comment: True, although, it seems to be deprecated. [find_installation()](https://mesonbuild.com/Python-module.html#find_installation) from python module is what they suggest instead. And it's nice because it has some handy features !

Comment: @barsoosayque: shouldn't it be: `r = run_command(python_exe, params, 'arg1', 'arg2')`

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the [key design considerations](https://mesonbuild.com/Use-of-Python.html#reimplementability) behind meson:

> Meson has been designed in such a way that the implementation language
>   is never exposed in the build definitions. This makes it possible (and
>   maybe even easy) to reimplement Meson in any other programming
>   language.

So, even though meson is implemented in Python, users may forget about this and concentrate on provided functionality which is, as you found it, extendable with **run_command** function.